# ValueError: demasiados valores para descomprimir (esperado 2) Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-urls

Tengo un problema en mi proyecto 'Django' y necesito ayuda con este error, el error ocurre cuando quiero crear migraciones, uso PyCharm para trabajar y a la vez uso la consola de cuya IDE, cuando ejecuto la creación de la migración "python manage.py makemigrations" me sale todo este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in exec
ute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in exec
ute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in autodis
cover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodisco
ver_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "c:\users\circi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\GoutApp\admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models.product import Product
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\GoutApp\models\product.py", line 34, in <module>
    class Product(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\GoutApp\models\product.py", line 40, in Product
    choiceGameCategory = MultiSelectField(choices=GameCategory)
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\multiselectfield\db\fields.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.max_length = get_max_length(self.choices, self.max_length)
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\multiselectfield\utils.py", line 31, in get_max_length

    return len(','.join([string_type(key) for key, label in choices]))
  File "C:\Users\circi\Documents\Django\Gout.io\ve\lib\site-packages\multiselectfield\utils.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    return len(','.join([string_type(key) for key, label in choices]))
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Este fracmento muestra como tengo el código en el archivo urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('GoutApp.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Este fracmento muestra como tengo el código en el archivo admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models.product import Product


class AdminProduct(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'Pricing', 'choicePrice', 'choiceApp', 'choiceGameCategory']


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Product, AdminProduct)
```

La manera en que el directorio está organizada es de la siguente forma:

[image: Así tengo mi directorio:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por una comunidad de Facebook me mencionaron una posible causa, y fue multiselectfield, la cual verifiqué y me salté la parte en que tengo que hacer de la siguiente forma ("H", "Hola), así que esa fue la solución.